# what is the 0 index in the print command when printing elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried this piece of code but I don't understand why we use the 0 index in {0[a]} .

```
Day={'a':'Saturday','b':'Sunday','c':'Monday',
      'd':'Tuesday','e':'Wednesday','f':'Thursday','g':'Friday'}

print('the first days is {0[a]} , second days is {0[b]}'.format(Day))
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` refers to the first argument passed to the `format(...)` function. `1` is the second, and so on.

Alternatively, you can pass name arguments to `format`, and use their names in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is referring to the first argument of the [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.
Your print is thus equivalent to

```
print('the first days is {0} , second days is {1}'.format(Day['a'], Day['b']))
```

or

```
print(f"the first days is {Day['a']} , second days is {Day['b']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is not for indexing the dictionary, it is for getting the first item in the `.format(..)` parenthesis.

Example:

```
>>> '{0} {1}'.format('Hello', 'World')
'Hello World'
>>>
```